# SQL Server Management Studio - Debugger buttons greyed

Tags: sql-server, ssms, windows, remote, debugging

I have for mission to enable Transact SQL from a remote computer. My database is on a server and i'm trying to use the debug from a computer on the same network. My firewalls are all open on both side. Both of my machines are in a domain, i'm trying to use the debugger with a user registered in the security connection and who gets the sysadmin rights. Everything looks OK, i can open the debugger but the buttons to step into the object are greyed.

When I try to debug on the machine itself it works without problem, but remotely I can't use F10 F11 etc .. You can see the pictures attached, where you can see the differences between local debugger screen and remote debugger screen:

- When it works on local: https://gyazo.com/5a900c7f961f9f43af16be20843162d3
- Doesnt work remotely: https://gyazo.com/7bd375164ca0ccf84dcb2fd8349fda04
- User configuration: https://gyazo.com/81a9ff4cd00adedb07791595ec8984ce

Does anybody have an idea of what's going on ? Let me know if you need any information.

Comment: FYI .. [SSMS TSQL Debugger is in deprecated list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#deprecated-features). Another reason to stop using it.

Comment: I'll transmit it but i don't think it'll be enough to convince my boss :p
Even if that sucks i've to find a solution, thank you for the link i'll try to make him realise that's a bad idea ! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to [open the network ports & firewall ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/configure-firewall-rules-before-running-the-tsql-debugger?view=sql-server-2017) between your desktop running SSMS, and the remote computer.

Just generally speaking, though, I'd highly recommend against running the debugger on a live server. You're going to force SQL Server to hold your locks open for longer periods of time, and you can easily cause a blocking storm. Instead, I'd strongly recommend debugging your code locally on your own dedicated instance of SQL Server. (Developer Edition is free.)

Comment: Hi ty for the quick answer, I already followed this Microsoft Doc, the firewall has been configured like this and that didn't solve the problem. What is strange is that i can open the debugger but then can't do anything. At the beginning I had a message saying there was a firewall problem but its not happening anymore ...